# Symfony formbuilder DateTime shows wrong date

Tags: symfony, datetime, formbuilder

I want to set the default value of `date` as current date, but I'm getting 2013.01.01 instead of current date.

```
$builder->add(
        'date',
        DateTimeType::class,
        [
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'empty_data'=> new \DateTime(),
            'date_format' => 'y-M-d H:i',
            'required' => true,])
```

How to set default date value as the current date when I submit the form? and if I want to edit the form, set that date to the existing value in my entity?

Comment: Found that `empty_date` is not usable here. Instead I need to use `placeholder`, but how to format DateTime to implement it?

Comment: symfony version, please?

Comment: Did you tried to construct `new \DateTime()`  in your entity?

Comment: 3.2.4 version. No I tried to use `'date' => new \DateTime()`, that works for creating, but when I want to edit it sets new current date instead of displaying existing one.

Comment: Did you set the default value of your field  as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in your database?

Comment: No, I didn't. I expect to write an `if` statement inside `'data'` field, but don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to construct `new \DateTime()` in your entity itself. Since you are not manually entering the current date value, you don't need to add the 'date' field in your form builder.

```
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * YourEntity constructor.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->setdate(new \DateTime());

    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return YourEntity
     */
    public function setdate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }
```